# Django - saving model via a form is not working

Tags: django, forms, model, save

I'm having a little problem with the .save() method in Django. For 1 form it works, for the other it doesn't. And I can't find the problem.

views.py

```
@login_required
def stock_add(request, portfolio_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('request.method is ok')
        form = StockForm(request.POST)
        print('form is ok')

        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid')
            stock = form.save(commit=False)
            stock.created_by = request.user
            stock.portfolio_id = portfolio_id
            stock.save()
            return redirect('portfolio-overview')
        else:
            print("nope")
    else:
        print('else form statement')
        form = StockForm()

    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'portfolios/stock-add.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class StockForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['quote', 'amount']
```

html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Add Stock</h1>

    <form method="POST" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=112)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='portfolios', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Portfolio'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Stock(models.Model):
    Portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, related_name='stocks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quote = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='stocks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.quote
```

If you look at the views.py file, when I submit the form, it won't even do print('request.method is ok')
I can add the stock via the admin page.

So I have no clew where to look anymore...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, an InteregerField (from models.py) needs a default value.
Either default=None (or another value).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you post a form and need a special url (like your' with an attribute), i like to set `action="{% url myview.views.stock_add portfolio_id %}"`

`action="."` will save to the same page without taking care of extra parameters (if needed)

Just pass `portfolio_id` in the `context` and that will work

Comment: Hi Maxime, Thanks for the answer. I've tried to add 'portfolio_id':portfolio_id to the context. But this didn't work. I've also tried action={% url 'stock_add'  portfolio_id %}, but this didn't work as well..... Any other suggestions? Or am I doing something wrong?